OneSignal api 400 bad reques
I want to send push notifications to all users using onesignal api, but I get a 400 bad request error.
const notification = {
    app_id: appId,
    included_segments: ['All'],
    contents: { 'en': 'Bu bir test bildirimidir.' },
    big_picture: 'https://panel.biletproject.com/documents/panelbiletproject/etkinlik/9CF4919F-C674-ABCF-E7AE2EB021CDB6DF.png',
    small_icon: 'https://biletproject.com/documents/images/phone_artibir.png',
    data: { url: 'https://biletproject.com/edetay?id=45' }
};

fetch('https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Basic ${btoa(apiKey + ':')}`
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(notification)
})


Please check what the response body actually contained. According to the docs, I think you should get an errors object containing more information.
